# Another unknown city - postmark -Anhui?

Tags: place-names

Can someone tell me the name of the city on this postal cancel? I believe it's from Anhui province from 1937, but I'm not sure.[image]

Answer (score 2):

安徽Ān​huī 杨溪镇 Yángxīzhèn = Yángxī town

Answer (score 2):

Please note that in that times, characters were written from right to left.

The postmark says

> 廿六年 六月 廿一

Which means 21st June, 1937 (literally, 21st, June, 26nd year. Republic of China was founded in 1912. Hence 1912 was the first year and 1937 was the 26nd year.).

The big characters in the top are

> 安徽
>   Anhui  province

The big characters in the bottom are

> 揚溪鎮
>   Yangxi town

Please look at the first character carefully by yourself. It may be 楊 as 楊 and 揚 are very very similar. Searching on the internet, I find there is a town by the name of 揚溪鎮 (simplified Chinese: 扬溪镇) in the county of 绩溪 (Jixi), prefecture-level city of 宣城(Xuancheng) , 安徽 province. Of course, there is still a chance that the first character is 楊 if the original name has been changed.